# Python executables file with sql query hangs

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pyodbc

```py
def test_job():
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver=SQL Server;Server=*******;Database=( *****;UID=******;PWD=********;Trusted_Connection=Yes;')

    todays_date = datetime.datetime.now().date().strftime ("%d-%m-%Y")
    
    MARCH_DATASET=pd.read_sql_query('select * FROM MARCH_2021',cnxn)
    
    todays_file=MARCH_DATASET[MARCH_DATASET.UPLOADED_DATE_CST==todays_date]
```

Comment: If you give trusted connection, you don't need to give a name and a password as trusted means to take it from windows credentials manager. If you still want to do it, you should write in the  `User Id=`  and not `uid=`. and also pwd is wrong. Your connection string looks like MySQL. You can see it here https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/. `Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;`

Comment: @TheFool - Your advice re: `Trusted_Connection=yes` is correct, but `UID` and `PWD` are in fact the correct parameter names as noted [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-odbc-driver-17-for-sql-server/).

Comment: @GordThompson after doing some web search, I see that both are valid. Your string is for ODBC and my one is for sqlClient DataProvider.  So It would depend on which driver the library is using. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937083/when-should-i-be-using-odbc-oledb-sqlclient-what-are-the-trade-offs

Comment: Well ok, its saying pyODBC so guess, in this case you are right.